# "Heck" in formal writing

Tags: formality

So I'm trying to make a proper transition to the next sentence and was wondering if I could use "heck" in such formal context.

> The AI will recognize people entering the apartment and greet them with their preference in lighting conditions and room temperature. It’ll play their preferred music and record their favorite shows. It’ll even make them their desired blend of coffee. **Heck**, It’ll even help me reduce costs by monitoring electricity and gas usage. In short, it’ll be amazing.

Comment: None of that paragraph could be characterized as "formal"/

Comment: "Heck" should be omitted. Its absence will not change the meaning of your paragraph.

Comment: What makes you so certain this should be formal writing?  This seems like a product review.  I don't think being formal is even called for here.

Comment: I guess by formal I meant in a way you would talk normally but somewhat better? Sorry, English isn't my first language.

Comment: When selling stuff the only rule is whatever works.  That and use sex, puppies, and the word "FREE" whenever legally allowed.  Formal writing can be a part of that but is not required.  Heck can add flavor, shock value, and regional appeal.  Making the statement seem less polished can add value by making the speaker seem more genuine.  That's if it's done well.  Done wrong it'll seem hackneyed.    Heck is a substitution swear word.  Not the sort of thing you'd use if you want to seem edgy like in a Mtn. Dew add.  So use it with care.  Thus saith the Prince of Insufficient Light, ruler of Heck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To heck with heck, let's fix that transition.

> The AI will recognize people entering the apartment, greeting them with their prefered lighting and temperature conditions, playing their preferred music, recording their favorite shows, and make their desired blend of coffee. It will even help reduce costs by monitoring electricity and gas usage. In short, it will be amazing.

If only it could drive me to work while I took a nap in the back seat.